# Automatic flag for compiler directive based on synthesis/simulation for xilinx/modelsim?

Tags: simulation, verilog, fpga, xilinx, modelsim

I've got a large verilog project that I'm synthesizing onto a xilinx fpga and simulating in modelsim.  There are a few modules wherein I'd like to simulate one version of said module and synthesize another.  For example I have a parameterized reset debouncer, which counts a few milliseconds.  Clearly for simulation this is annoying so before I simulate I change the debounce count to something like 10 clock cycles.  Currently I have a flag (`define SIMULATION), which I comment out for synthesis.  Then in my modules I utilize compiler directives like 'ifdef to compile a different version of the deouncer depending on synthesis/simulation:

```
 `ifdef SIMULATION
   button_debouncer #(1,5, 24)
`else
   button_debouncer #(1,12000000,24)
`endif
   resetdebounce(/**/
         // Outputs
         .debounced     (reset),
         // Inputs
         .clk           (clk),
         .button        (~reset_button));
```

While this works it requires that I comment in/out `define SIMULATION every time I switch from modlesim to ISE.  I often forget, waste time, etc, etc.

Is there an automatic way to determine which tool is being used?  Eg I could say something like `ifdef XILINX or`ifdef MODELSIM instead of my `ifdef SIMULATION hack?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both @CliffordVienna and dwikle solutions work well.  Depending on your tool chains either or both solutions work great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Xilinx ISIm User Guide (UG660, v14.3, page 44), isim predefines the macro XILINX_ISIM (to the value 1). So just use XILINX_ISIM instead of SIMULATION.

Comment: For Vivado looks like the macro is `XILINX_SIMULATOR`. See https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation/Predefined-Macros

Answer (score 5):

Mentor Graphics simulators (ModelSim and Questa) will define the `MODEL_TECH` preprocessor macro.

So you can do:

```
`ifdef MODEL_TECH
  // code for simulation with modelsim
`else
  // code for synthesis
`endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `+define+SIMULATION` to vlog as a command-line argument.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do you know if that would result in a permanent define or if I'd have to do that every time I open modelsim?